# how to @use scss with map variable

Tags: sass

I can do this:

`@use 'bootstrap' with ($red:'red', $blue: 'blue');`

and can't:

```
$vars: ($red:'red', $blue: 'blue');
@use 'bootstrap' with $vars;
```

Is there a way to pass `with` vars as a map or file?

Comment: May I know what do you want to do with the values of the '$vars'

Comment: just for short and clean code, and sometimes maybe I need share $vars with multiple @use